# How can i do a count(*) during a loop?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a cursor full of info, and some of them have the same attribute(lets say matricula) but i need to insert the content of the cursor in a table where matricula is a PK. So no same attribute are allowed.

To solve this i am doing a two select count(*) to verify that 
   1st there is no license plate in the table, and i can do the insert statement.
   2nd if there is a license plate i will check if there is some null attribute and update them.

I do all of this inside the fetch loop statement.

```
c1 := funcObterInfoSemanalVeiculos(data_GuardarInfo);

LOOP
   FETCH c1 INTO data_inicio, data_fim, matricula, nr_viagens, soma_duracao, soma_km;
   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;


    -- Verify if registry exists in the table
    SELECT count(*) into verificacao     
        FROM resumosveiculos rv
            WHERE   rv.matricula = matricula and
                    rv.soma_km = soma_km;  


    -- Verify if resgitry as some null values              
    SELECT count(*) into verificacao_2   
        FROM resumosveiculos rv
            WHERE   rv.matricula = matricula and
                    rv.soma_km = 0;             


IF (verificacao = 0) THEN

   INSERT INTO resumosveiculos (
    instante,
    data_inicio,
    data_fim,
    matricula,
    nr_viagens,
    soma_km,
    soma_duracao)
       VALUES((SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  FROM DUAL),
       l_data_inicio,
       l_data_fim,
       matricula,
       nr_viagens,
       soma_duracao,
       soma_km
       );

ELSIF (verificacao_2 > 0 and nr_viagens != 0 and soma_km != 0  and soma_duracao != 0 ) 
THEN

    Update resumosveiculos rv
    SET rv.nr_viagens = nr_viagens,
        rv.soma_km = soma_km,
        rv.soma_duracao = soma_duracao
    Where rv.matricula = matricula;

ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Not inserted-> ' || matricula);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('--------------------------------------------'); 
END IF;
END LOOP;
```

When a row is inserted a the verification always show that the current value exist altough if was never inserted in the table.

There is no rows in the table before the procedure is executed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is-- it appears that you know how to do a `count` inside a loop.  The entire approach seems a bit overcomplicated, though.  It looks like this whole thing should be a single `merge` statement.

Comment: Just change the names of the variables. It is same as the column names of the `resumosveiculos` table. In count query, it is comparing column with itself.

Comment: `rv.matricula = matricula` will compare column with itself as plsql engine identified name as column name and not variable name. Change the variable name from `matricula` to something like `v_matricula` and same for all other variables. Let me know if it works then I will put it as an answer.

Comment: Please describe your intention, there will be for sure a simpler and more elegant solution. Somehow suspicious is the update on `rv.matricula` eventhough the table `PK` seems to be `matricula,soma_km` (are you sure you want to update all rows with zero and non-zero values of `soma_km`?

Comment: @Tejash that was the answer ! 

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you are using variable name which is same as column name of the table.

```
rv.matricula = matricula
```

Here, `matricula` is the name of the `column` as well as the name of the declared parameter. You are confusing PL/SQL compiler. Haha!!

But PL/SQL compiler will consider it as the `column name`. This is how it behaves. Hence, condition will always be satisfied(true) which is causing problem in your case.

As I commented, please change the name of the variable to something like `v_matricula` and enjoy coding.

Cheers!!